How to Apply Different Filters for Each yField in MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline in Blazor WASM?
I'm building a Blazor WASM application that generates charts using MongoDB. My current implementation aggregates data from a MongoDB collection and supports multiple yFieldvalues for grouping and aggregation.
The current code works for a single match filter that applies to all fields, but I need to add individual filters for each yField. Here's the relevant part of my code:
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost("GetChartDataAsync")]
    public async Task<string> GetChartData(chartclass chart)
    {
        var collection = GetMyDb().MDB.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("d_sales_date");


        var groupStage = new BsonDocument
{
    { "_id", $"${chart.xfield}" }
};

        foreach (var y in chart.yfield)
        {
            
            var aggregationOperator = y.aggregate switch
            {
                Aggregations.Sum => "$sum",
                Aggregations.Min => "$min",
                Aggregations.Max => "$max",
                Aggregations.Average => "$avg",
                _ => "$sum"
            };


            //y field filters

            groupStage.Add(y.name, new BsonDocument(aggregationOperator, $"${y.name}"));
        }

        var pipeline = new List<BsonDocument>
{
    new BsonDocument("$group", groupStage)
};

        var results = await collection.Aggregate<BsonDocument>(pipeline).ToListAsync();

        return results.ToJson();
    }

    public class chartclass
    {
        public string xfield { get; set; } = "";
        public List<YField> yfield { get; set; } = new();
    }

    public class YField
    {
        public string name { get; set; } = "";
        public BsonDocument filter { get; set; } = new();
        public Aggregations aggregate { get; set; } = Aggregations.Sum;
    }

I need to allow each yField to have its own filter (defined in yField.filter) so that I can match specific subsets of data for each aggregation.
For example:
For yField1, apply a match filter where fieldA > 100.
For yField2, apply a match filter where fieldB == "value".
Desired Behavior:
I want to modify the pipeline to include conditional $match stages for each yField before adding its aggregation logic to the $group stage.
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
